# CSS listen to keyboard actions

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask is there something in CSS that features the function as

```
document.onkeypress = returnKey;
```

in javascript? Or other keyboard actions listener in CSS?

Comment: i believe not, the closest is :focus, :hover, etc.

Comment: Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) are style sheets. Style sheets do not provide JavaScript-like functionality, they provide styles/styling for your document...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No there is not, CSS is static styling.

There are pseudo-classes for certain actions such as `:hover`, `:link`, `:active` and `:focus` etc, but these are element specific.

Your best bet would be to assign keydown handlers, and provide a separate class with your styles, thus mixing JavaScript and CSS to get the effect you desire. In the handler, you can apply the class to the element you desire.

A simple (and rough) jQuery example to emulate something like a `:keydown` pseudo-class on `body` would be something like this:

```
$('body').keydown(function() {
    $(this).addClass('keydown');
}).keyup(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('keydown');
});
```

.. with a corresponding class like this:

```
.keydown {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No.

CSS is for styling, not scripting. To handle keyboard events, use JavaScript.